# Codeskulptor code doesn't work in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, codeskulptor

I wrote a code in CodeSkultor, which made use of Simplegui module but that's not available in Python 2.7, obviously. I know we can make use of SimpleGUICS2Pygame module and I have set it up along with pygame but the below code for a simple Guess the Number game still doesn't seem to display the graphics. Couldn't attach a screenshot. Any ideas, anyone? Link to CodeSkultor program is here - http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user40_G13NSFMPzs_4.py

```
try:
    import simplegui
except ImportError:
    import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui
#import simpleplot

# define global variables
n = 0
min = 0
sec = 0
tenth_sec = 0

is_running = False

count_stop = 0
count_success_stop = 0

# define helper function format that converts time
# in tenths of seconds into formatted string A:BC.D

def format(t):
    global sec
    global tenth_sec
    global min
    #global is_running

    sec = int (t / 10)
    tenth_sec = t % 10
    min = int (t / 600)

    #return sec
    if sec < 10:
        return str(min) + ":0" + str(sec) + ":" + str(tenth_sec)
    elif sec >= 10 and sec <= 59:
        return str(min) + "0:" + str(sec) + ":" + str(tenth_sec)
    elif sec >= 60:
        sec = sec % 60
        if sec >=10:
            return str(min) + ":" + str(sec) + ":" + str(tenth_sec)
        else:
            return str(min) + ":" + "0" + str(sec) + ":" + str(tenth_sec)

    #is_running = True

# define event handlers for buttons; "Start", "Stop", "Reset"
def button_start():
    global count_start
    global is_running
    global check
    timer.start()
    is_running = True
    check = True

def button_stop():
    global count_stop
    global count_success_stop
    if timer.is_running():
        count_stop += 1
        if tenth_sec == 0:
        count_success_stop += 1
    timer.stop()

def button_reset():
    global n
    global count_stop
    global count_success_stop
    n = 0
    count_stop = 0
    count_success_stop = 0
    timer.stop()

# define event handler for timer with 0.1 sec interval
def timer_handler():
    global n
    n = n + 1
    #print n

# define draw handler
def draw_handler(canvas):
    canvas.draw_text(format(n),[120,150],30,"Black")
    canvas.draw_text(str(count_stop),[230,40],20,"Green")
    canvas.draw_text("/",[250,40],20,"Green")
    canvas.draw_text(str(count_success_stop),[265,40],20,"Green")

# create frame


# register event handlers
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Stopwatch", 300, 300)
frame.add_button("Start",button_start)
frame.add_button("Stop",button_stop)
frame.add_button("Reset",button_reset)
timer = simplegui.create_timer(100, timer_handler)

# start frame
frame.start()
frame.set_draw_handler(draw_handler)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must start the frame **at the end**.

See https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Compatibility.html

"With SimpleGUICS2Pygame, `Frame.start()` is blocking until `Frame.stop()` execution or closing window. So timers must be started *before*, and states must be initialized *before*. (Or maybe after by a handler function.)"

Comment: That helped only partially in that I can now see the score at the upper right corner but the timer itself in the middle is not working.

Comment: It's work for me! In your CodeSkulptor link, I just swapped the 2 last lines.

    frame.set_draw_handler(draw_handler)
    frame.start()

Comment: Sorry for a super late response but it worked for me too later. Thank you!